# node.js output stream as download

Tags: node.js, express, download, stream, response

i implemented a way to download files without saving them on disk before.. using the officegen package for npm:

```
var documentObject = officegen('docx')
// fill with data
// download via express
res.setHeader('content-type', 'contentType1')
res.setHeader('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=file1.docx')
documentObject.generate(res)
```

This is it for my download...it works fine for this file format.

But what i would like to do now, add an other file type for download, like .txt:

```
var writer = new streams.WritableStream()
writer.write('some text')

var reader = new streams.ReadableStream();
var output = reader.pipe(this.writer)

res.send(output)
```

The txt file gets downloaded...but when i open it, i can see the content is a long json ({"_writableState":{"highWaterMark": ...)

Anybody could help me with this issue?

Greetings and thanks

I am using stream from:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-streams
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using either the standard node.js HTTP response object, or express.js (which extends the standard response class) then your `res` object is already an instance of `WriteableStream`, and you should be able to pipe directly to it:

```
reader.pipe(res);
```